# has no method appendTo for my object

Tags: jquery

```
input = "<input type='text'>";
input.appendTo('li');
```

is there anything wrong here? why it said no method appendTo? I want an input field to append to li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `input` is a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object and it does not have a method called `appendTo`

```
input = $("<input type='text'>");
input.appendTo('li');
```

You need to call [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) on a jQuery wrapper object as it is provided by jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Do it like that, because as @Arun pointed out, it's a `string` and not a *jQuery object*:

```
var input = $("<input type='text'>");
input.appendTo('li');
```

Just make sure that you have something like that in you page:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

In order that your code will be able to ***append to*** the `li` tags.

Answer (score 0):

First wrap a string with `$` for getting jQuery object and try calling jQuery objects method

```
 $(input).appendTo('li');
```